# how to see preview of xml in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed android studio and when i open an xml file i cant preview it or see pallete [image]

If i go to View-tool windows - palette it wont show again.
I want to see preview of xml file like in eclipse

Comment: I don't think the Windows version has this option :(. My Mac version has it, Windows 7...not so much.

Comment: I am not sure about it, i saw few people having it work on Windows

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is you are looking at the XML file located in this project location:

> build/res/all/debug

You need to view it in this location:

> src/main/res/layout

Comment: thanks! that's what I hate of Java: the zillion folders/files you have