# Android Studio "design tab" missing

Tags: android, android-studio

The "Design" tab in Android Studio's graphical editor, and the preview tab at right, are missing. How can I cause them to appear?

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625350/how-to-see-preview-of-xml-in-android-studio/16625493#16625493)

Comment: Yea, but there is not tab or option in the dropdown menu...

Comment: They said that you have to update to SDK Version 22, but i downloaded it just a few hours ago...

Comment: I had the same problem. Restarting Android Studio fixed it.

Comment: Just click the activity_main.xml file it will open that view

Comment: I had to do `File -> Invalidate Caches` to get it to show up. Somehow Android Studio got into a bad state again.

Answer (score 17):

In order to restore the tab, you need to close an xml file, which contains layout and reopen it again within editor. No need to restart android studio. It is, probably just a little bug.

Comment: Using Android Studio 3.5. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

Go to "View" in the top menu and click on "Tool Buttons". The preview tab at the right side should appear after that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go on **View Tab** then click on **Tool Windows** there will be preview tab on right just click **Preview Tab**.

Comment: "Design" and "Preview" are different tabs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java tab at the top Right side of android window. Click on that tab and the Package explorer tab will apear again