# How re-enable design palette in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, palette

I recently made the switch to Android Studio as my default IDE for Android development. When designing my UI I normally use the palette in the design view to assist in arranging the widget on the preview screen.Recently something weird happened, It just disappeared and I can't seem to re-enable it. Normally I would see the little Palette button on the side but now its gone. When I open another project I see the palette but not show this current project I'm working on.

[image]

When I open another project in Android Studio I see the palette tab.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824306/text-design-tab-missing-new-android-project-on-android-studio-ide

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723821/android-studio-design-tab-missing

Comment: I have the Text and Design tab. It's the palette button that's not showing and I see no way to reenable it.

Comment: Agreed, not a duplicate. Not sure how to fix this one, though.  Sorry.

Comment: Is it over in the far left column by the Project and Structure buttons? It can move over there if you unselect it from pinned mode. http://postimg.org/image/ko1u189dz/

Comment: Alternatively try going to View > Tool Windows > Palette

Comment: I have the same problem, the palette option in there is not clickable for some reason.....do i need anything from the sdk manager download?Also seems i have two palette references in there and both are inactive and i cant activate them...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've just figured this out!  If you double click on your .xml file tab at the top it will maximize the designer window.  Then on the left you can drag the window to shrink and it will reveal the palette.  Then just click on the tab on the left to open the project window.

Answer (score 20):

try the Design/Text tabs in the lower left of the layout window

[image]

Comment: When I'm designing a form I believe the `Design` tab should be default as that is what all WYSIWYG developers are used to. Just drag and drop. For drag and drop you always want to see some control tool box and palette sort of thing right in front of you. Very funny to be finally able to figure out the design/text tabs in bottom left corner.

Answer (score 5):

The palette can be shrunk to 0 width.  This can be expanded by hovering next to the left edge of the design window, and finding the right-most expand position.

Answer (score 3):

If you have only the designer and the properties showing and the Properties is on the right, you can get the palette back by switching to a left or right view.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the .xml file tab. Select "split  vertically". This will open another Design that shows the palette again.

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio 2.3.3, and the answer I was looking for:

*Window -> Restore Default Layout* (Shift+F12)

Answer (score 2):

First Close All The Tabs Then Open res->layout->activity_main.xml
you will able to see design tab at activity_main.xml

[image: activity_main.xml]

[image: design tab downside]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Try to switch between Design/Text tabs at the bottom left of the editor.]

Try to switch between Design/Text tabs at the bottom left of the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You must have something in the layout resource highlighted. I also had to compile without an error.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was traversing

```
src->main->res-layout->content_main.xml
```

then `open content_main.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You have to be in the 'Design' tab (as opposed to the 'Text' tab) at the bottom of the middle window (the one that shows the phone).

Answer (score 0):

Resolve this by starting a new project. Then select blank activity for type and the res>layout folder will now exist with the main xml file.