# Can't re-open Component Tree on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just downloaded Android Studio, and while I was trying to familiarize myself with the setup, I accidentally closed the Component Tree. I'm at very beginner level, and in all of the results I've come across, I didn't understand or it didn't work for me. How do I find the Component Tree again?

Edit: Here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-enable "component tree" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483917/re-enable-component-tree-in-android-studio)

Comment: Screenshot img pls

Comment: @this.girish no, I found that one earlier but I didn't understand the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the "Component Tree" of the XML preview, this can be collapsed & expanded alike all other sidebars; it might be at the bottom-left of the XML preview window, where "Palette" is. It just sometimes requires double-clicking, in order to expand that panel. I tried, but I didn't manage to hide or remove it; if it is really missing, the Android Studio installation might be broken (needs reinstall).

Comment: I selected Android, but that didn't pull up the component tree either- it only pulls up the app and gradle script folders.

Comment: @W.Han Have understood what you mean and updated my answer.

Comment: Ah I found it on the bottom left of the XML Preview window like you said, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try anyone of these ways to restore hidden or misplaced component tree window-

1. **Try Windows > Editor tabs > Close all**.
   then open your activity.xml again in your design mode. (Worked for me)
2. press shift **F12**, it should restore your window to default view.(or just go to Windows > Restore default layout).
3. hover over the square icon in the bottom left corner and click on component tree.

Answer (score 0):

ALt + 7 control the structure(tree) display or not