# Palette de-selected in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have already tried out maximising the window but it doesn't work unfortunately (Based on the discussions from the previous posts). Is there any way to get back the palette?

The previous question that is being asked is linked here

[How re-enable design palette in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550594/how-re-enable-design-palette-in-android-studio)

In the View->Tool Windows, the Palette is inactivated here and is not clickable for some unknown reason.

I attach a screenshot herewith

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2d7n.png)

Comment: If there is a previous question related to this question, it is essential that you link the question in your post, so that people who have not seen it before will know what you are talking about. Thank you!

Comment: I have linked the previous question.