# Android studio palette is missing

Tags: android, android-studio

the palette in my android studio is missing, I have tried the following solutions:

[image: Here is my screenshoot]

- Rebuild the project
- double click on the.xml file tab at the top it will maximize the designer window. Then on the left, you can drag the window to shrink and it will reveal the palette (from: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550594/how-re-enable-design-palette-in-android-studio))
- Restart the computer
- Open a new project
- Change the app theme

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're also missing all the ConstraintLayout controls

Comment: @JaydeepPatel I have tried it, it failed.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Other than reinstalling Android Studio? Submitting a bug report? Making sure those SDK packages were actually installed?