# How to switch to design editing in android studio for designing layout of the activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I can't switch to design editing in android studios when i want to edit the xml file of the layout file. There are no button for changing to text or design on the bottom of the codes. [Screenshot of android studios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu6fB.png)

Can someone help me fix the problem?

Comment: as your screenshot your project does not getting resources or not properly  build in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Where the 'design/text' tabs were missing.

I had switched to the dark theme and thought maybe that was the issue, so went back to Preferences / Appearance (under IDE Settings) switched back to Default Theme, and that reset everything correctly for me.

I could also then switch again to Dracula theme and the tabs were still there, so seems like switching themes is a way to reset the IDE windows/tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the **IDE** .It may be helpful to show the design /Text tab..

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:
View -> Tool Windows -> Preview

Same question was answered here: [Where is Android Studio layout preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660039/where-is-android-studio-layout-preview)

If it didn't help, try methods mentioned here: [Android Studio "design tab" missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723821/android-studio-design-tab-missing)

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, change the code tree from Package to Android as bellow link may help.

[See screenshot here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOSLV.png)

Hope this will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As of today in July 2022, here are the actions I have taken:

1. Look for the device manager icon
2. Choose your option to add a device (virtual or physical)
3. In case of a virtual device select the screen size and download it. In the case of a physical device, you have to pair it whether by wifi or QR code scan.