# Navigation Preview/Editor not showing

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated android studio:

[image]

And now I cant see navigation preview, only the xml.

[image]

It not appear preview or design option.

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723821/android-studio-design-tab-missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723821/android-studio-design-tab-missing)?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it only occurs in navigation.xml file

Comment: Just as a guess. Did you put your xml in the `navigation` folder?

Comment: Try to restart AS or even invalidate cache + restart.

Comment: I invalidated already cache + restart. Yes, navigation.xml is in the navigation folder. Before updating, it worked

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Android Studio 3.2 beta 1 they disabled the editor by default, you need to open settings(File -> Settings), in the left pane select 'Experimental' and check 'Enable Navigation Editor'

[image]

Comment: another time to use my second account to +2 this :-)

Comment: In android studio 3.3.1 it does not have this checkbox in the experimental section

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.3, navigation editor is not in setting->experimental. you can create a new directory in resources folder by name navigation and in that you can create a new navigation.xml file.