# Cannot find Jetpack in Android studio 3.2 Beta 2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, android-studio-3.2

I've been using Android studio 3.2 canary 15 (Preview) for a while now and it was working fine with jetpack (Really slow, but fine)

The problem is every time I try to update (Tried beta 1 and 2), I cannot see the jetpack package (When I create a new project, the 'Fragment & Activity+ ViewModel option is not present)

And a project that is built on Jetpack navigation is now not working properly showing a **generated.java** package. And the nav_graph file is not showing the design part.

[image]

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling again, invalidating cache, deleting the whole SDK and installing it again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065148/navigation-preview-editor-not-showing/51069590#51069590

Comment: You're a life saver!! Thank you

Comment: @Alex Now the Navigation is working, but I can still see the generatedJava package. Is that normal?