# Design tab is not visible in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Design tab is not visible in Android Studio. How to enable it ?

View - Window tools - viewer is not visible.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio "design tab" missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723821/android-studio-design-tab-missing)

Answer (score 1):

The view that you are looking for is called the "preview" window in android studio.

You have to open a layout view in your project. Navigate to src/main/res/layout/ in your project and select the xml layout file you want to work with.

If the preview window doesn't automatically open up, you can open the view by selecting from the tool bar View>Tool Windows>Preview

There will be a "Design" and "Text" tab at the bottom of the xml layout.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer and upvote it if it solves the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this problem. Try File > Sync Project with Gradle Files. This can also help with configuration problems